# Fix Dropbox sync remotely

Tags: macos, ssh, sync, dropbox

I'm having intermittent trouble getting Dropbox to sync on a remote machine.  I don't know what the cause is, but it will sync fine for months then stop.  I'm trying to debug this over SSH on OSX (Yosemite). I know that:

- Dropbox is running, but it's sleeping
- The file(s) in question are synced on other devices and the DB server

I've looked at Dropbox help and googled for several minutes now to no avail.  It appears there isn't great cl support for Dropbox on OSX.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Dropbox just wouldn't wake.  Killing the app and restarting did the trick, eg:

```
kill `pgrep Dropbox`
open -a Dropbox
```